# Sandbox Refreshes with Different Connected Apps Configurations for Prod/Test

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, connected-apps, sandbox-refresh

Currently looking for ideas on how to handle sandbox refreshes, where production and the sandboxes use different configurations in a Connected App. That is, each environment has a Connected App where a different certificate and URL is used.

Is there an easy way to handle this without manually re-setting up Connected Apps when doing refreshes?

It seems the only possible way to automate this would be with the `sfdx force:mdapi` since unlocked packages can't be used with Connected Apps. I wanted to check if this is actually the recommended method though as it doesn't seem great.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @identigral It is an approach for the URL, not sure about the certificate or consumer key though.

Comment: Consumer key will be different, the refresh ensures that. Certificate - best practice is to use a different keypair for each org but you can upload the same keypair to all orgs, if you produce your own keys.

Comment: @identigral Will be using a unique certificate for the Connected App per org. So this is that part where I'm the least certain on how to go about swapping the certificates after a refresh. Solving for the URL can be done a few ways it seems, one of which is answered in the link you provided.

Comment: The easiest way is to not clone the app. You can have one connected app serving all pre-production orgs, for example. If you choose to clone, you'll have to deal with certs, consumer id and so on after every refresh. Certs can be uploaded via [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_certificate.htm) or manually